# Fun Learning Exercises Recommendations

Tags: self-improvement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find programming puzzles and challenges?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/756/where-can-i-find-programming-puzzles-and-challenges)

Recently in our workplace we have been playing [Design Pattern Poker](http://industriallogic.com/games/pp.html). This is fun and really helps the participants to understand design patterns and to think of useful way to apply them.

Can anyone recommend any other similar, fun games that will help us improve our development skills?

Comment: How about [algorithm dances](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/130829/25936)? Bit too much? :)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The other question was asking for puzzles that can help an individual can develop their problem solving skills. This refers to games a development team can play as a group to improve the teams skills as a whole.

Comment: You should revise the question and make it a bit clearer that it's not a duplicate and that the answers to the other question don't answer your own. Then you should post a [meta question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/) asking for the question to be re-opened. I _think_ the questions are not duplicates, but that's not really evident from and I can't be certain. I'll gladly cast a re-open vote if you revise and clarify it a bit.